# Generate statistics and graphics from SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dataset

After somes researchs, I am asking for tips and suggestions.

I am doing for a corporation a C# software used to interact with a SQL server database to fill and retrieve informations about "events". Now my boss wants to see graphical representations of the data and some stats (pie chart, etc...) My boss would like something flexible, what I mean: The user can decide to analyse the number of injuries during the five last years or anything else available on the database.

It's for a corporation, so my sofware can't be open source and we don't have a lot of money to spend on it. I found some librairies, but they cost something around 600$ or more...

But for me, I would like something relatively easy to use, I would like to spend less than a year (...) on it.

Meaby our expectations are too high, so if our requirements are impossible, just say it. Please.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There is already [SQL Server Reporting Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) and lets not forget [Excel external connect capabilities](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx).

Comment: If you want graphs and report for free just use SSRS.

Comment: Please also consider the cost of your time: it makes no sense to say "I can't spend $600 but I can spend a year on it". A year of anyone's time is worth a lot more than $600, so you and your boss should absolutely consider commercial solutions if they save you time. A developer's time is usually the most expensive part of any system, so buying tools is frequently worthwhile. But as Remus pointed out, you already have SSRS so why not start there? And open-source software is not necessarily a problem in commercial environments; it all depends on the license.